# How to run this ruby file that needs an argument?

Tags: ruby

I just wanted this function to run and get the output, but I can't seem to make it run.

I installed Interactive Ruby for this.

This is the code:

```
class Float
def to_sn # to scientific notation
"%E" % self
end

def self.from_sn str # generate a float from scientific notation
("%f" % str).to_f
end
end

# Pass in filename as only argument
if ARGV.size != 1 
 puts "Usage: ./converSTL.rb [stl filename]"


 exit
end
begin
  original = File.new(ARGV[0], "r")

  # Read first line - check binary or ASCII
  tempLine = original.gets
  if tempLine.include? "solid"
    outFilename = ARGV[0].sub(/\.stl/i, '-binary.stl')
    puts "#{ARGV[0]} is in ASCII format, converting to BINARY: #{outFilename}"
    outFile = File.new(outFilename, "w")
    outFile.write("\0" * 80) # 80 bit header - ignored
    outFile.write("FFFF")   # 4 bit integer # of triangles - filled later
    triCount = 0

    while temp = original.gets
      next if temp =~ /^\s*$/ or temp.include? 'endsolid' # ignore whitespace
      temp.sub! /facet normal/, ''
      normal = temp.split(' ').map{ |num| Float.from_sn num }
      triCount += 1
      temp = original.gets # 'outer loop'

      temp = original.gets
      vertexA = temp.sub(/vertex/, '').split(' ').map{ |num| Float.from_sn num }
      temp = original.gets
      vertexB = temp.sub(/vertex/, '').split(' ').map{ |num| Float.from_sn num }
      temp = original.gets
      vertexC = temp.sub(/vertex/, '').split(' ').map{ |num| Float.from_sn num }

      temp = original.gets # 'endsolid'
      temp = original.gets # 'endfacet'

      outFile.write(normal.pack("FFF"))
      outFile.write(vertexA.pack("FFF"))
      outFile.write(vertexB.pack("FFF"))
      outFile.write(vertexC.pack("FFF"))
      outFile.write("\0\0")
    end
    outFile.seek(80, IO::SEEK_SET)
    outFile.write([ triCount ].pack("V"))
    outFile.close

  else
    outFilename = ARGV[0].sub(/\.stl/i, '-ascii.stl')
    puts "#{ARGV[0]} is in BINARY format, converting to ASCII: #{outFilename}"
    outFile = File.new(outFilename, "w")
    outFile.write("solid \n")
    original.seek(80, IO::SEEK_SET)
    triCount = original.read(4).unpack('V')[0]
    triCount.times do |triNdx|
      normal = original.read(12).unpack('FFF')
      vertexA = original.read(12).unpack('FFF')
      vertexB = original.read(12).unpack('FFF')
      vertexC = original.read(12).unpack('FFF')
      original.seek(2, IO::SEEK_CUR)

      outFile.write("  facet normal #{normal[0].to_sn} #{normal[1].to_sn} #{normal[2].to_sn}\n")
      outFile.write("    outer loop\n")
      outFile.write("      vertex #{vertexA[0].to_sn} #{vertexA[1].to_sn} #{vertexA[2].to_sn}\n")
      outFile.write("      vertex #{vertexB[0].to_sn} #{vertexB[1].to_sn} #{vertexB[2].to_sn}\n")
      outFile.write("      vertex #{vertexC[0].to_sn} #{vertexC[1].to_sn} #{vertexC[2].to_sn}\n")
      outFile.write("    endloop\n")
      outFile.write("  endfacet\n")
    end

    outFile.write("endsolid \n")
    outFile.close
  end
  original.close
rescue => error
  puts "Error: #{error}"
end
```

And everytime I try to run it, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Can you write the error message you have instead of giving the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a script that can be run from cmd with

```
ruby convertST1.rb file.stl
```